# using BCP to upload CSV to sql server, errors around dates

Tags: python, sql, csv, bcp

We have written a program that writes a Pandas dataframe to a CSV and then uses that CSV to upload to a table in our SQL server.

However, the index to the dataframes are dates, while all other values are floats. When trying to use the bcp utility to upload to the sql server, we get either one of two errors. Our sqlBulkCopy function is below.

Either we get the error that there is an invalid character value for cast specification.

```
Error = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]Invalid character value for cast specification
```

We switched the cast specification to -n, then we get the error that there is an 'invalid field size for datatype'.

```
Error = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]Invalid field size for dataype
```

Anyone any tips as to what is going on? How can we use bcp to upload a csv that has dates in the first column and floats everywhere else.

```
def sqlBulkCopy(server = None, database = None, username = None, password  = None,
            table  = None, filename = None):
    '''Use BCP to bulk upload a CSV to a specific database with a given  table
    name.'''

    print('Loading data from ' + filename + ' to SQL table ' + table + ' using BCP...')
    sys.stdout.flush()

    #-c indicates to copy data using the character type (not unicode)
    #-t, indicates that ',' is the value separator
    #-F2 indicates to skip the header (first line) so that copy starts on line 2
    #-S is server name, -U is username, -P is password
    #For more information on BCP syntax, visit https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx

    subprocess.check_call('bcp ' +  database + '.dbo.' + table + ' IN ' + 
                      filename + ' -c -t, -F2 -S ' + server + ' -U ' + 
                      username + ' -P ' + password)
```

Comment: Can you add the error (precisely I mean)? Also output the result of the string concatenation you do in check_call

Comment: I added the exact errors.

Comment: The exact string concatenation is 'bcp databaseName.dbo.tableName IN fileName -c -t , -F2 -S serverName -U userName -P passWord' (can't include the actual database names etc.)